# How can I prevent CakePHP validating fields not in $fieldList?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I use CakePHP2.7.5 and my Model's `save` function is failing because it is trying to validate fields that are not specified in the `$fieldList` parameter.

According to the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html), `save` method takes `$fieldList` as third parameter to limit the saved fields to those listed in `$fieldList`.

```
Model::save(array $data = null, boolean $validate = true, array $fieldList = array())
```

I call `save` in the model like this:

```
$this->save($data, true, ['name', 'place']);
```

$data is like this:

```
[ 'ModelName' => [ 'id' => $id, 'name' => 'abcdef', 'place' => 'ghijklmn' ] ]
```

but it fails because validation errors occur for the required fields that are not presented in `$data`.  Is it supposed to work in this way?

Do I have to put some dummy data in `$data` for the required fields?

Comment: I think that the correct behaviour because if I create some validation rules for my model I want to rely on it so that the data that is stored to the database is always valid. Do you want to store datasets to your database that does not match the validation rules?

Comment: Sorry if that's not clear, but my point is that there is a valid record already and I want to update only 'name' and 'place' fields in the example above.  I'm not touching any other field, so I do not need validation for those fields.  I was expecting that specifying $fieldList would work for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set *required* to false in the validation rule:

```
public $validate = array(
    'description' => array(
        'alphaNumeric' => array(
            'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
            'required' => false,
            'message' => 'You have to enter a valid description'
        )
);
```

}

[CakePHP 2.x Validation: 'required'](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#required)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.  In Cake's `Model::save` function, the second parameter `$validate` could be an array, and this problem occurs only when it is an array. (so, my example in the question above was not accurate.)

So, this one should work as intended (validates and saves 'name' and 'place' only),

```
$this->save($data, true, ['name', 'place']);
```

but this one doesn't,

```
$this->save($data, ['validate' => true], ['name', 'place']);
```

and actually I was doing like this. (because I had to make 'atomic' false and this is how to do it.)

```
$this->save($data, ['validate' => true, 'atomic' => false], ['name', 'place']);
```

In my case, this is the solution.

```
$this->save($data, ['validate' => true, 'atomic' => false, 'fieldList' => ['name', 'place']);
```